# Android implement automatisation

Tags: android, android-intent, automation

Everyone knows Tasker.
The optimal way to use Tasker would be to create a Plugin. But then you can't use other automation Apps like Llama (except you also build a plugin for them of course).

I saw a clever workaround for this. since nearly all automatisation Apps are able to start Intends, some Apps like the one for Franco.Kernel or ElementalX have classes which can be startet from such Apps to do Stuff. For ElementalX it looks like this: `flar2.elementalxkernel.powersaver.DISABLE_POWERSAVE`.

I like this idea and want to implement this to!

but I have some questions...

- Are these just normal classes like every other Activity and Class in my Project?
- How do I get my Context in those Classes?
- Can those classes access all other functions and SharedPrefs in my App?
- Is it possible to hand over parameters like `Ints` or `Strings`?
- What else do I need to keep in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The example you gave is an intent from the application `ElementalX Kernel` (now replaced by `EX Kernel Manager`)

The intent is made public by adding  `android:exported=“true”`  to the app's manifest. This means other apps like Tasker can use it.

Within the `ElementalX Kernel` app, there is a broadcast receiver that listens for this intent.  When the intent is used, it triggers further actions.  In your example, when the intent `flar2.elementalxkernel.powersaver.DISABLE_POWERSAVE` is broadcast, the app will receive the broadcast and call the methods that disable powersave mode.